# mod_rewrite not working on linuxmint 14 Nadia

Tags: xampp, linux-mint, lampp

I'm developing my web on Xampp for Linux 1.8.1 on my Linuxmint 14. Everything works fine, except I can't use .httaccess file. I have searched on google, and this problem related to mod_rewrite. So I tried several workaround I found upon Googling, but unfortunately none worked.

I have tried changing

1. AllowOverride none to All
2. Options all
3. Order allow, deny
4. Allow from all

to related Directory config on my /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf file.

But it do nothing..

Some other folks tell me to use this command

```
 $ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

But, it results "command not found" on my linuxmint 14.

I also tried to find /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, but there's no such path exist.

Please help, if anybody know what's wrong with my xampp system. I want to use my .httaccess file, that's the essence.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the apache2 is installed and running.

you can do that by writing the following in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`